# Into which tables/attributes should we upload shipping info?

Tags: magento2, api, shipment-tracking

We are handling all inventory management and order fulfillment in Salesforce, which will be synced with our new Magento2 implementation.  When products are shipped out to the customer, we would like to push this info back into Magento so that the customer can review on their order status.

Which tables/attributes (objects/fields) should be updated with tracking number, date shipped, etc.?

I know it probably has something to do with http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/salesShipmentRepositoryV1 but I was hoping someone else has come across this issue before.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0 You have to use listed tables

```
  sales_shipment  # Main Table
  sales_shipment_grid # For Billing & Shipping Info
  sales_shipment_track # For Tracking of Order
```